# In Linux, is there a way to keep whole drives offline?

Tags: disk, hdparm

I am looking for a feature similar to the ability to set a drive offline in Windows Disk Management:

[image: Windows Disk Management]

The problem is that I don't know exactly what Windows is doing there. But it seems to affect the whole disk.

Answer (score 4):

Because it took me some time to figure out how this could be done, I am posting this as a Q&A and answer my own question. **NB:** I will accept any (working) answer with an alternative method that allows select drives to be marked in the way shown below *but at boot time*.

After recalling some of the fancier (and dangerous things) `hdparm` is able to do, I decided to look it up and indeed `hdparm` is the solution here.

The following `hdparm` options are relevant:

> `-y`
>   Force an IDE drive to immediately enter the low power consumption **standby** mode, usually causing it to spin down.  The current power mode status can be checked using the `-C` option.
>
> `-Y`
>  Force  an  IDE drive to immediately enter the lowest power consumption **sleep** mode, causing it to shut down completely.  A hard or soft reset is required before the drive can be accessed again (the Linux IDE driver will automatically handle issuing a reset if/when needed).  The current power mode status can be checked using the `-C` option.

Most likely disks marked offline in Windows are in a mode similar to what `hdparm` calls the **sleep** mode above. Alas, as [Stephen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) pointed out, Linux will still happily spin up the drive even if put to sleep. So the OS doesn't ignore the drive this way, which the offline marker in Windows does.

(If you know for sure which setting it corresponds to, please create an answer or edit mine.)

Comment: That’s not quite the same as Windows’ offline status: it puts the drives to sleep, but it doesn’t tell the operating system to ignore them. Any attempt to access the drives will power them back up.

Comment: @StephenKitt yep, unfortunately you seem to be right (going by the documentation). I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a storage device using `echo 1 > /sys/block/device-name/device/delete` where `device-name` may be `sda`.

Reference: [RedHat Doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/online_storage_reconfiguration_guide/removing_devices)

> ## Ensuring a Clean Device Removal
>
> 1. Close all users of the device and backup device data as needed.
> 2. Use umount to unmount any file systems that mounted the device.
> 3. Remove the device from any md and LVM volume using it. If the device is a member of an LVM Volume group, then it may be necessary to
>      move data off the device using the pvmove command, then use the
>      vgreduce command to remove the physical volume, and (optionally)
>      pvremove to remove the LVM metadata from the disk.
> 4. If the device uses multipathing, run multipath -l and note all the paths to the device. Afterwards, remove the multipathed device
>      using multipath -f device.
> 5. Run blockdev –flushbufs device to flush any outstanding I/O to all paths to the device. This is particularly important for raw
>      devices, where there is no umount or vgreduce operation to cause an
>      I/O flush.
> 6. Remove any reference to the device's path-based name, like /dev/sd, /dev/disk/by-path or the major:minor number, in applications,
>      scripts, or utilities on the system. This is important in ensuring
>      that different devices added in the future will not be mistaken for
>      the current device.
> 7. Finally, remove each path to the device from the SCSI subsystem. To do so, use the command echo 1 >
>      /sys/block/device-name/device/delete where device-name may be sde, for
>      example.
> 8. Another variation of this operation is echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_device/h:c:t:l/device/delete, where h is the HBA
>      number, c is the channel on the HBA, t is the SCSI target ID, and l is
>      the LUN.

Comment: fair enough, removal seems to be an option. But how do I re-enable a device on-demand without a reboot or physically having to disconnect and reconnect the device in question?

Comment: @0xC0000022L  To explicitly add a SATA/SCSI single disk, there is a preferred method and a depreciated method per Red Hat documentation. The preferred method uses the `echo “<C> <T> <L>” > /sys/class/scsi_host/host<H>/scan` syntax.  The depreciated method uses the `echo “scsi add-single-device <H><C> <T> <L>” > /proc/scsi/scsi` syntax.